# Making a scroll method with Up and Down arrow in C#

Tags: c#, methods, scroll

I'm building a text based game with three other for a project at school.

We have a log where every line that has been written will be written.

I always take a height of 45 lines and a width of 145, so you have 45 lines to write in, I have made a GUI so after that has been written there are only 33 lines height left to write in and 143 width.

Once the page is full the program writes over my GUI and I want to fix that problem.

You can look at the game and code yourself at https://github.com/LegacyProgrammer/TextBasedWitcherGame

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: You have a GUI? Are you using WinForms or Console? (not that it matters without including relevant code in the question)

Comment: Just including a repo isn't very helpful...Try to slim down your question and post some code some people can easily help you.

Comment: I'm using Console, but I cant upload a debug or code because i don't have any  idea how to get what I want... If you look at the game at github and download it for yourself, you will get what I ment to do.

Comment: No one is going to download some random code and run it. You need to do the work to extract the part of your program causing the problem. The reason this is a required step is that the process of preparing a question that others can answer often means you can answer it yoiurself.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void ScrollUpAndDown()
    {
        if (Program.busy != true)
        {
            ConsoleKeyInfo KeyInfo;
            KeyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);
            switch (KeyInfo.Key)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                    CurrentLine--;
                    indexLog--;
                    if(indexLog >= Program.Log.Count)
                    if(CurrentLine == 5)
                    {
                        ClearText();
                        CurrentLine = Program.intResol_Long - 7;
                    }
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(1, CurrentLine);
                    Program.busy = true;
                    Console.WriteLine(Program.Log[indexLog]);
                    break;

                case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                    CurrentLine++;
                    indexLog++;
                    if (CurrentLine == Program.intResol_Long - 7)
                    {
                        ClearText();
                        CurrentLine = 5;
                    }
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(1, CurrentLine);
                    Program.busy = true;
                    Console.WriteLine(Program.Log[indexLog]);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

This is the code i have for Scrolling down and up now, indexlog is  the amount of strings in the log and current line is the currentline.